# Is there a way to add/reassign characters in an existing font?

Tags: fonts

I'm using the font [Jack Input](http://www.dafont.com/jackinput.font), and its missing the curly braces, is there a way to edit it and reassign the curly braces to characters from another font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)

> An outline font editor that lets you create your own postscript, truetype, opentype, cid-keyed, multi-master, cff, svg and bitmap (bdf, FON, NFNT) fonts, or edit existing ones. Also lets you convert one format to another.

[image]